# Can I add my outlook.com account to Outlook 2016 for Mac by using calendar and contacts like Outlook 2013 for Windows does?

Tags: windows, macos, mac, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

With Outlook 2013 for Windows it is possible to add an outlook.com account as follows:

[image]

It includes my calendar and my contacts, too. Works perfect. Outlook 2016 for Mac offers the same option (it is just not saying anything about Exchange ActiveSync compatibility. I think the Windows version is using SyncML which is used on mobile devices. E.g. works perfect on my iPhone):

[image]

But this approach results in the following account settings:

[image]

As you can see it has created an imap account instead of using SyncML.

Is there any change to get my outlook.com contacts and calendar running?

Or is it not supported in the Mac version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well done with your question.

> Or is it not supported in the Mac version?

Not supported on your Outlook 2016 for Mac. Only IMAP is supported for Outlook.com

[Outlook 2016 for Mac does not support CalDAV nor CardDAV](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoutlook/outlook-for-mac-2016-wont-sync-365-calendar-and/20c4ab1a-801a-4479-b1d6-b35fd7830ac4?page=3)

> outlook.com which is not fully supported on mac. (Outlook for Mac does
>   not currently support CalDAV or CardDAV.) This means notes, calendar,
>   contacts etc will not work. the only thing you have is mail.

More supporting details: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124932/setting-outlook-com-contacts-and-calendar-on-osx